# Learning Magento CE 2.4 without spending money on courses?

Tags: magento2, learn-magento

I'm a former frontend developer (JS, CSS3, Bootstrap etc.) with some OOP PHP experience. I've built a fully functional Magento 1.9 site with 80K products and built a smaller site with Magento 2.1 although the theme was not mine.

It's been a couple years break from web development and I've noticed a lot has changed with M2. Adobe acquired it, no more installation wizard, ElasticSearch is required etc.

I read a lot of people mentioning the Magento U courses for learning but those are incredibly expensive. Are there folks who are learning for free just by exploring the code base and asking questions when stuck?

How should one go about brushing up on PHP 7, Magento 2.4 and everything in between if you're poor?

Comment: Your question doesnt fully linked to MSE. Please check official documentaion and you will have great clarity. Suggestion: Solid php and OOPs knowledge is required before development in magento. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

To start learning Magento 2, Its not required to do magento u course. Yes its plus if we can do magento u course but not must as magento already providing alot resource to do study using dev docs.

You can refer the below links:

Magento Developer Documentation - https://devdocs.magento.com/

Alan Storm blog - https://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/

Youtube Tutorials - https://www.youtube.com/c/MaxPronko/playlists

https://belvg.com/tutorial

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-tutorial/

There are so many other blog tutorials that you can refer for your magento 2 learning journey.

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this out these are free tutorials along with that you can also follows resource shared by Pankaj Pareek.

https://magento2tutorial.magestore.com/

https://www.pronkoconsulting.com/ecommerce-blog/5-ways-to-learn-magento-from-scratch-with-no-coding-skills